# Getting a 500 Response error after Replaying a recorded browser session using Radview's Webload tool, from HTTP POST attempt

Tags: load-testing

I've been using Radview's Webload IDE tool for a couple of test simulation projects and it has worked well. But for this one scenario where I have a client web session for a login a screen, it would always fail with a 500 Response error for a particular HTTP post as the page loads. 
When I try the scenario to load the page manually with a browser it works fine with no issues.

During the recording I would set clear browser cache and cookies and no luck. And I've also tried out many configuration combinations from the "Recording and Script Generatinon Options: Post Data" settings.

```
/***** WLIDE - URL : http://192.168.2.2/ - ID:2 *****/
wlGlobals.GetFrames = false 
wlGlobals.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
wlHttp.Get("http://192.168.2.2/")

// END WLIDE

/***** WLIDE - URL : http://192.168.2.2/Api.ashx?c=Images&action=GetSettings - ID:3 *****/ 
wlHttp.Header["Referer"] = "http://192.168.2.2/"
wlHttp.FormdataEncodingType = 1
wlHttp.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
wlHttp.FormData["c"] = "Images"
wlHttp.FormData["action"] = "GetSettings"
wlHttp.Post("http://192.168.2.2/Api.ashx"+"?c=Images&action=GetSettings")

// END WLIDE
```

Anybody with experience with Radview's Webload can give me some suggestions?
I noticed that commenting out the formdata "c" and "actions" lines works. but later I notice a similar error which requires a sessionID in the URL so I'm not sure if I can comment out the formdata "sessionID" line.

Comment: source code? anything you think might be causing it? leave those kind of things in your question.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I was still editing my question. 
but i added more info.

Comment: I suspect that some item of dynamic data from the initial request is not being passed with the login request. You need to think much more about the initial request, its response and then the data sent with the login. Try some web searches for "dynamic data" or for "correlation" in web testing.

Answer (score 1):

To run the API from Webload you need to specify the authorization if its secured.

Answer (score 0):

Using `wlHttp.FormData` is not the same as adding a parameter to the URL for a POST request.

FormData will be send as part of the post-data request body, while adding it to the URL will send it as a query string - your sever probably expects one form but not the other.

Contact RadView support if you can't get it to work and they'll help you